# RecyclerView not populating data in ViewPager tab

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-contentprovider

I have implemented a basic setup of ViewPager, RecyclerView, and ContentProvider. I seem to be able to query data without any problem but I am not able to show the content using RecyclerView in the ViewPager tab.

Full code is available here - https://github.com/sudhirkhanger/PopularMovies

```
public class FavoriteFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie_list, container, false);

        // Set column size to 2 for default and portrait
        // and 3 for landscape orientations
        int column = Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.grid_portrait));
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 1) {
            column = Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.grid_portrait));
        } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 2) {
            column = Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.grid_landscape));
        }

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), column));

        ArrayList<Movie> mMovieArrayList = new ArrayList<Movie>();

        ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();

        Cursor cursor =
                resolver.query(MovieContract.MovieEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.MovieEntry.TITLE));
                    String movie_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.MovieEntry.MOVIE_ID));
                    String poster = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.MovieEntry.POSTER));
                    String backdrop = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.MovieEntry.BACKDROP));
                    String overview = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.MovieEntry.OVERVIEW));
                    String vote_average = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.MovieEntry.VOTE_AVERAGE));
                    String release_date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.MovieEntry.DATE));

                    Movie movie = new Movie(title, release_date, poster,
                            vote_average, overview, backdrop, movie_id);
                    mMovieArrayList.add(movie);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();

        for (Movie movie : mMovieArrayList) {
            Log.d("FavoriteFragment List", movie.getTitle());
        }

        mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), mMovieArrayList);
        mMovieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);
        return rootView;
    }

    public static FavoriteFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        FavoriteFragment fragment = new FavoriteFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);
        mMovieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    MovieAdapter mMovieAdapter;
}
```

As you can see below that ArrayList contains the data.

```
04-25 22:02:36.216 4718-4718/com.sudhirkhanger.app.popularmoviesstageone W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for PopularFragment{d7cf0b6 #1 id=0x7f0c006b} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
04-25 22:02:37.757 4718-4718/com.sudhirkhanger.app.popularmoviesstageone D/FavoriteFragment List: Whiplash
04-25 22:02:37.757 4718-4718/com.sudhirkhanger.app.popularmoviesstageone D/FavoriteFragment List: Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice
04-25 22:02:37.757 4718-4718/com.sudhirkhanger.app.popularmoviesstageone D/FavoriteFragment List: Star Wars: The Force Awakens
04-25 22:02:37.757 4718-4718/com.sudhirkhanger.app.popularmoviesstageone D/FavoriteFragment List: The Shawshank Redemption
04-25 22:02:37.757 4718-4718/com.sudhirkhanger.app.popularmoviesstageone D/FavoriteFragment List: The Godfather
04-25 22:02:37.757 4718-4718/com.sudhirkhanger.app.popularmoviesstageone D/FavoriteFragment List: Interstellar
04-25 22:02:37.757 4718-4718/com.sudhirkhanger.app.popularmoviesstageone D/FavoriteFragment List: Captain America: Civil War
04-25 22:02:37.757 4718-4718/com.sudhirkhanger.app.popularmoviesstageone D/FavoriteFragment List: The Jungle Book
04-25 22:02:37.757 4718-4718/com.sudhirkhanger.app.popularmoviesstageone D/FavoriteFragment List: The Revenant
04-25 22:02:37.757 4718-4718/com.sudhirkhanger.app.popularmoviesstageone D/FavoriteFragment List: Jurassic World
04-25 22:02:37.757 4718-4718/com.sudhirkhanger.app.popularmoviesstageone D/FavoriteFragment List: Mad Max: Fury Road
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

ImageView height is set to `wrap_content`. In case when there's no image then the view will be invisible especially in `RelativeLayout`. You don't have this problem when you have `LinearLayout`.

Due to typing error in DetailsFragment.java I set image path to be `final String poster = parcelableExtra.getReleaseDate();` which is wrong.

There are multiple fixes.

1. Switch to LinearLayout
2. Set a fix height for ImageView.
3. Make sure image is not broken.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I think you need to set the adapter in onViewCreated.

Answer (score 0):

First, move everything inside your `onCreateView` to `onViewCreated`. Just return `rootView` there. It is not needed, but it is good coding practice and will help later when you are trying to fix life cycle bugs. Also, delete your `onResume` method. You are not doing anything in there that is helping.

Second, Move these lines:

```
mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), mMovieArrayList);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);
```

to right below this line:

```
ArrayList<Movie> mMovieArrayList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
```

Then, after you have populated your list with all of the data, call this line to tell the recycler view that the list has changed:

```
mMovieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

---

**So all said and done, you will have this:**

```
public class FavoriteFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    MovieAdapter mMovieAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie_list, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle b) {
        // Set column size to 2 for default and portrait
        // and 3 for landscape orientations
        int column = Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.grid_portrait));
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 1) {
            column = Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.grid_portrait));
        } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 2) {
            column = Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.grid_landscape));
        }

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), column));

        ArrayList<Movie> mMovieArrayList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), mMovieArrayList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);

        /* do all of your cursor stuff to populate the mMovieArrayList */
        ......

        // notify adapter to recycle 
        mMovieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static FavoriteFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        FavoriteFragment fragment = new FavoriteFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the project and:

- The `MovieAdapter` is okay because I put breakpoints in `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` and they were hit.
- I cannot verify that the queries are ok but they are probably ok by looking at your logging that you have posted.

## The actual problem...maybe

the thing that seems to be the problem is that `list_item.xml` layout! I changed it into a `LinearLayout` instead of a `RelativeLayout`, and it works now.

list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="1dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_title_size"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageview"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/list_title_text_size"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

evidence!:

[image: evidence]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the problem might have been in layout. The core of the issue is that ImageView is set to `wrap_content`. Image link got broken due to a typing error. If there is no Image then ImageView will not be shown at all. That's what was going on.